# How do i know the amount of how many recently accepted commits from pull request are accepted

Tags: git

How do i know the amount of how many recently accepted commits from pull request are accepted. How do I do this automatically? I can't seem to find an API or a git command that does this.

For example, John recently did a pull request to a repo, and Mark(repo) owner accepted his pull request, with this 5 new total commits has been added. How do I get the "5" value.

Comment: Is your remote GitHub? What happens in your GitHub repo when a pull request is accepted? A true merge, or a squash?

Comment: Keep in mind that pull requests are not a Git feature.

Comment: Note that just because someone on GitHub *accepts* (merges) a PR doesn't mean they took the *original commits*. In particular, using the "squash and merge" web button will turn the N original commits into a single new commit. (The original commits remain in the PR, which remains in GitHub forever.) This is just a longer version of what @matt said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information about pull requests using the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls):

> ### Pulls
>
> The Pulls API allows you to list, view, edit, create, and even merge pull requests.

If you read the docs, you'll see there is even an [API to list commits
in a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#list-commits-on-a-pull-request). Given a pull request number, you can request:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/commits
```

This returns a JSON list of commits, so the answer to your question is
"the length of the list". Using the [github
cli](https://github.com/cli/cli) and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), we can write, for example:

```
gh api /repos/git/git/pulls/1297/commits | jq length
```

This returns `2`, the number of commits in pull request `1297` to the `git/git` repository.

You can use `curl` instead of the `gh` cli tool (although in the case you'll have to handle authentication yourself when necessary):

```
curl -sf https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/pulls/1297/commits | jq length
```

Comment: But we haven't even been able to get the OP to confirm that this _is_ GitHub we're talking about (though I'm pretty sure it is, of course).

Comment: Well, then the OP can decide if this answer is appropriate or not! I mean, if they ever come back :)